# What does the teacher's clothing choice say about him?

Tags: character-analysis, japanese-language, natsume-soseki, i-am-a-cat

In chapter 2 of *I Am a Cat* we see this chunk of text:

> He continues to wear his black cotton crested surcoat and, thereunder, a quilted kimono of hand-woven silk which, supposedly a keep-sake of his elder brother, he has worn continuously for twenty years. Even the most strongly woven silk, cannot survive such unremitting, such preternaturally, perennial wear. The material has been worn so thin that, held against the light, one can see the patches sewn on here and there from the inner side. My master wears the same clothes throughout December and January, not bothering to observe the traditional New Year change. He makes, indeed, no distinction between workaday and Sunday clothes. When he leaves the house he saunters out in whatever dress he happens to have on. I do not know whether this is because he has no other clothes to wear or whether, having such clothes, he finds it too much of a bore to change into them. Whatever the case, I can’t conceive that these uncouth habits are in any way connected with disappointment in love.
>   <sub>*I Am a Cat*, chapter 2</sub>

Such a detailed description of what he chooses to wear should say a lot about this character. What can we learn from his choice of dress?